# Leer página web y procesar contenido con jsoup

Tags: java, android, jsoup

Estoy intentando hacer una aplicación de farmacias de guardia en principio solo para mi localidad. El único sitio donde se cuelgan las farmacias de guardia es en esta página: http://www.cofcastellon.org/farmaciasGuardia.jsp

Llevo varios dias intentando sacar las farmacias con [jsoup](https://jsoup.org/) pero me es imposible, no lo consigo. Lo único que he logrado es hacer un `WebView`, pero de ahí no consigo sacar los datos para implementar en un mapa.

```
public class BrowserTest extends AppCompatActivity {
WebView webview;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

String url = "http://www.cofcastellon.org/farmaciasGuardia.jsp";
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
webview = new WebView(this);
WebSettings webSettings = webview.getSettings();
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
setContentView(webview);
new DownloadHTMLTask().execute(url);
```

}

```
private class DownloadHTMLTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {


        Document doc = null;
        String html = "";
        try {

            URL url = new URL(urls[0]);
            doc  = Jsoup.connect(url.toString()).get();
            doc.select("#header > div").remove();
            doc.select("body > div > div.main > section").remove();
            doc.select("#footer").remove();



        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }



        return doc.toString();
    }
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        webview.loadDataWithBaseURL("http://www.cofcastellon.org/farmacias.jsp", result, "text/html", "utf-8", "");

    }
}
```

}

este es el main y me muestra la pagina solo con el mapa, que es lo mejor que pude hacer,

no había puesto el codigo por que en realidad lo que quiero es pasar los datos de las farmacias de guardia a un mapa creado con google maps api, el problema es que no se como hacer y lo único que se me ha ocurrido fue hacer este webview

Comment: Hola ajat, bienvenid@. Has de mostrarnos codigo que tengas y los fallos que te da o el resultado obtenido por que es distinto de lo que esperas. Pega el codigo que mencionas de la webview o algo que hayas intentado. Sin mas datos no podemos ayudarte. Un saludo

Comment: ya he editado el mensaje con el código, que lo había puesto como respuesta

Comment: hice [este fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9c9gurry/) (HTML sacado de la web de tu pregunta), igual te sirve de algo .Un saludo

Comment: no conocia eso de fiddle, voy a investigar, muchas gracias¡¡¡¡ 

esto podría pasarlo a una aplicación con la api de google maps y que me las marcase en el mapa?? es que de ahi no salen las coordenadas